# Different result from bash and source commands

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, zsh

I have a very simple script name tt.sh like this:

```
listFile=("A" "B" "C" "D")
echo ${listFile[1]} ${listFile[2]}
```

I tried to test this script with *source* and bash, but get a different result:

```
./tt.sh 
B C
source tt.sh
A B
```

Why does the *source* command take the start of the array from 1 instead of 0?
I'm using MacOS

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce on Linux bash 4.4.20(1)-release.

Comment: @nhthai, which version of MacOS are you using?

Comment: As my accepted answer, the problem comes from different behavior of bash and zsh. Thank folks for your check!

Comment: Why did you tag this with "linux"? Why with "zsh"? Why "shell"?

Comment: @RudyMatela : You are obviously sourceing from zsh. You can't expect the same behaviour if you are using a different shell. Create a bash subshell and source from there - you will see that they behave the same.

Comment: From the zsh man page about sourcing a file: _Read commands from file and execute them in the **current** shell environment._

Comment: @user1934428.  I'm not the original question asker, I merely edited the question.  But you are right, nhthai was sourcing from zsh.  If you check the accepted answer from 6 days ago you'll see that the problem has been solved.  nhthai has has already acknowledged that sourcing from zsh was the problem in the first comment of the accepted answer.  -- Best Regards -- Rudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mac, but here's what I can reproduce on Arch Linux (2021):

```
$ cat >tt.sh 
listFile=("A" "B" "C" "D")
echo ${listFile[1]} ${listFile[2]}
^D

$ bash tt.sh 
B C

$ zsh tt.sh 
A B
```

When I run the script with bash, it shows `B C`.  When I run with zsh, it shows `A B`.

Are you really using bash on the terminal you're sourcing to?  You can double-check with:

```
$ echo $0
bash
```

If the above shows bash, it means you are.  If it shows zsh, it means you are using zsh so you *will* see the zsh behaviour when you source.

[Starting with macOS Catalina, the default is zsh](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050).  If you would really like the bash behaviour, you could try swiching your default shell on Mac settings.

Comment: Got it. I'm using zsh, seems the "source" is belonging to it. Thanks for your help @Rudy.

Comment: Happy to help!  :-)  @nhthai, btw, to get a quick bash session from zsh, just type bash.  Then your source will behave like you want it to.  :-)

Comment: You can make `zsh` arrays behave more like `bash` arrays with `setopt KSH_ARRAYS` as well.

Comment: @nhthai `source` is a shell built-in, not an external command.

Answer (score 1):

When you source it the current shell is used, and when you execute the executable mentioned in shebang is used.

bash index starts from 0, some other shells have array index start at 1.

Most likely your current shell is not bash.